# What and where is mdimport

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, weblogic-10.x, workspace

Does anybody with weblogic portal knowledge know what jar file has the "mdimport" ant task definition. It's part of the build file created by the ant export script for wls10.0 but no longer works for 10.3. Any clue or ideas where to find the definition of this

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here. `your-portal-home"/workshop/com.bea.workshop.cmdline.ant.core_1.0.200.200906102316/workshop-antlib.jar`

Answer (score 0):

The mdimport task is defined in the xml file antlib.xml.  This will be defined in a different jar file depending on your version of weblogic.

```
<typedef name="mdimport"
          classname="com.bea.wlw.antlib.eclipse.ImportProjectMetadataTask"/>
```

For example it is define in weblogic92/workshop/lib/wlw-antlib.jar for WLI 9.2.2.

It might be easier to find the jar file by doing a recursive search for the ImportProjectMetadataTask class in all jars.